# Limit Microsoft OAuth authentication to only authenticate webapplication, not all microsoft services

Tags: javascript, firebase, azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory

I am using firebase for a website, where users can sign in with their microsoft accounts via OAuth 2.0:

```
import {getAuth, signInWithRedirect, OAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth";

(...)

const provider = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
const auth = getAuth();
signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
```

It prompts the Microsoft Single Sign-on with a redirection work-flow.

The authentification works nice with firebase, except one detail:
When I sign in with the Microsoft account in the browser for the webapplication, I am *also* signed in to my complete Office 365 account in the background and other potential microsoft sites.

So if I open a new tab and go to the my Outlook 365 online mail, then I am already logged in since I logged into my webapplication. If I happen to forget to log out from the webapplication, my entire mailbox, calendar with all the microsoft account information are exposed.

I have looked through all the pages and settings in the Azure Portal where I set up application/tenant id's, looked at Scopes and looked at OAuth 2.0 parameters from the Mirosoft documentation,but I can't find anything about this issue.

Single sign-on is originally made as a convenience for the user, but in my case I would like to prevent it as a security measure.

How can I limit the microsoft sign-in to only authenticate in the webapp/firebase project, and nothing else?

Comment: Interesting question! It would really kill the purpose of SSO. BTW, why would you want the SSO to work for your particular application only? What's the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is - you can't do that.

SSO is exactly what it means - Single Sign-On. The user logs in once and can use different apps without the need of authenticating again. You ask Microsoft to verify the identity of the user for you. Microsoft logs the user in and gives you back the answer. But it means, that on this browser the user will be able to use other Microsoft services as they already verified their identity.

The only thing you can do is to inform your users about the security risks and tell them to make sure to log out at the end of their work (you can then log them out at Microsoft as well).

If MS supports backchannel initiated log out, then you can try to implement some action that will check if your user's session is still active, and if not, then initiate a logout at MS. I don't know if they support it though.

Comment: Regarding logout, firebase does not log out the SSO when signing out with their API, it only log out the firebase authentication. However, I can use the microsoft redirect logout, through https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout - however this does not log out all the Microsoft services. If the user has visited their Outlook mail in another tab, he will still be signed in there. Do you happen to know if there is a way to present the user with choice to log out *all* the Microsoft services (without just telling the user to do so)?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such way. Otherwise, you would be able to logout a user from Outlook with your own app. I don't think Microsoft would allow anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yea, I understand that programatically signing someone out from all the Microsoft services would be prone for abuse. However I wish there was an option where Microsoft served a page similar to my link in the first comment (Oauth logout), where you could be presented for all the Microsoft services the SSO is currently managing, and choose to sign out one, serveral or all services from this page.